# Dependency Errors while installing Wine Ubutnu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: wine

eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.4~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: sorry i forgot it is Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Comment: You are trying to install a package clearly marked 'groovy', not 'focal'. You cannot mix versions. Install a 20.04 package on your 20.04 system.